# План разработки приложения Android

Tags: android

Как нужно составить план разработки приложения ?

К примеру,

- нарисовать на бумаге/в фотошопе дизайн экранов
- создать слои в IDE
- реализовать базовый механизм работы
- добавить возможность настройки отображения или доступа
- применить стили и дизайн целиком
- интегрировать рекламу или спец. google services.

Answer (score 2):

начинаем с миндмапы, где набрасываем мысли, потом пишем функциональное задание, потом можно набросать концепт в Axure RP или чем-то подобном, потом тех задание и дизайн.
после отдает программистам.
лучше нанять менеджера проекта с опытом, это сократит расходы на разработку.

Comment: Я сам себе хочу написать план. Так как произвольная разработка не есть хорошо. Вечно что-то забываешь и потом приходится дописывать или переделывать целиком, а это не всегда проходит успешно.

Comment: @web_alex, миндмапа и функциональное задание, помогут вам избежать большей части такого плана проблем.

Comment: а Вы можете посоветовать добротный пример, по которому я бы смог себе составить всё необходимое ?

Comment: @web_alex, вот ссылка на набросок миндмапы сайта - https://mm.tt/563015623?t=CuEjpQsLnO